# What issues need to be considered when using HTML5shiv?

Tags: html

I am thinking about starting to use some HTML5 elements in my sites. With the varying lack of support for HTML5 in Internet Explorer I was considering using HTML5shiv. I have read that I would need to set the CSS for various unrecognised elements to be block level and also the  possibility of issues with loading HTML5 elements via ajax.

I would like to know what issues others have encountered when using this script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to dynamically load HTML5 elements you'll need the [innershiv](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/). You'll also need to bear in mind that if the IE user has JavaScript disabled, it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the existing solution to be highly unreliable when used in real world scenarios - it's fine for noddy little "hello world" examples but as soon as the pages start getting more complex then you will find that styles will stop applying on some requests etc.

It's not a very nice answer, but the truth is that if you need to support older IE versions then you basically can't rely on being able to style HTML5 elements reliably. If you can get away with using the elements but use superflous markup (divs etc.) to do things like layout then you might get away with it, but then it depends what you consider to be the lesser of the two evils : Loads of noddy markup or no IE support.